# How can I save my toggled class names?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to make a function to toggle the language for my website. I'm doing this by toggling classes with JavaScript, but if I reload the page or go to another it changes back to the original. How can I save the changes that JavaScript makes?

```js
function langToggle() {
  if (document.getElementById("contenten").className == "show") {
    document.getElementById("contenten").className = "hide";
    document.getElementById("contentnl").className = "show";
    document.getElementById("myBtn").value = "Nederlands";

  } else{
    document.getElementById("contenten").className = "show";
    document.getElementById("contentnl").className = "hide";
    document.getElementById("myBtn").value = "English";
  }
}
```

```css
.hide{
 display: none;
}

.show{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<button id="myBtn" onclick="langToggle()" value="English">change language<i class="fa fa-globe"></i></button>

<section id="contenten" class="show">
  English
</section>
<section id="contentnl" class="hide">
  Dutch
</section>
```

I only want to use JavaScript or PHP

Comment: Your question is not so much about classes, but about persisting data across navigation. For that you need to either save the status on the server or client side. As you only want to use javascript, a server solution is out. Client solutions are based on cookies or localStorage (and its variants). There are lots of questions/answers about those two on StackOverflow.

Comment: you're right maybe it is better server side but i'm still learning and i'am not that advanced in php and javascript but if I can get an answer  it doesn't matter that much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `localStorage` (or `sessionStorage`, depending on whether you want it to be cleared when the browser closes), like this:

```
// Update the display on page load
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", showLang);

function showLang() {
    // read the last saved language, defaults to 'en'
    var lang = localStorage.getItem('lang') || 'en';
    document.getElementById("contenten").className = lang == 'en' ? 'show' : 'hide';
    document.getElementById("contentnl").className = lang == 'nl' ? 'show' : 'hide';
    document.getElementById("myBtn").textContent = lang == 'nl' ? 'To English' : "Naar Nederlands";
}

function langToggle() {
    // read, toggle and update the language in local storage
    localStorage.setItem('lang', localStorage.getItem('lang') == 'en' ? 'nl' : 'en');
    // adapt the display accordingly
    showLang();
}
```

Note that the button does not have a `value` property, you need to use `textContent` instead.

Comment: it does work but I will be killed by my teacher if I use it in my html. so is there a way to put it externe(not how, if it's possible ik can probably find it ).

Comment: In that case you should use PHP, and Ajax in your JavaScript to send any change of language to the server. Or if you prefer a solution with a cookie in JavaScript instead of localStorage, I could provide that, but the two are not really that different.

Comment: I have used once a 'window.evenListner' to load a code later but didn't work here but it should be possible.

Comment: Ah, is that the problem your teacher would have? In that case see the update I did with `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', showLang)`. With that you can place the script wherever you want.

Comment: Thanks for saving my life:). You have helped me a lot with this problem, thanks.

Comment: wacht je bent nederlands? nice

Answer (score 0):

You questions is actually about sessionStorage (html5 feature, supported even on IE8!!!!). More about this feature: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

In your case:

```
function langToggle() {
  var isNederlands = document.getElementById("contenten").className == "show";
  document.getElementById("myBtn").value = sessionStorage["lang"] = isNederlands ? "Nederlands" : "English";

  if (document.getElementById("contenten").className == "show") {
    document.getElementById("contenten").className = "hide";
    document.getElementById("contentnl").className = "show";

  } else{
    document.getElementById("contenten").className = "show";
    document.getElementById("contentnl").className = "hide";
  }

}
```

And then.. on your page `Load` event:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").value = sessionStorage["lang"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cookies` or `sessionStorage` for this purpose in javascript.

Comment: I already looked in to that but I really can't find out how tho use that with my code. I'am not really good in javascript so if you can show me how to use it would be great